# Uint8ClampedArray alternative or make Uint8Array produce a clamped string of byte values

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, typed-arrays

I'm working on this real head scratcher!

I'm successfully adding byte values to a Uint8ClampedArray and using the array to generate a byte string using this function:

```
this.utf8ArrayToStr = function(array) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            s += String.fromCharCode(array[i]);
        }
        return s;
};
```

This works a treat and successfully generates the correct byte sequence.

The problem is that not all browsers support Uint8ClampedArray and I specifically need it to work on Android browsers.

I tried using a standard Uint8Array but it results in extra byte values in the resulting string, causing erroneous behaviour.

I also found a small shim here, but it did not work, again producing extra output:
https://gist.github.com/gengkev/2295355

Is there anyway I could make Uint8Array act as Uint8ClampedArray, or more specifically, clamp the values while generating the string in the function above?

UPDATE: It looks like I'm getting somewhere using an standard array but there's still some messed up characters causing problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be using Uint8Array to store your data - it simply doesn't work like a Uint8ClampedArray. For example:

```
a = new Uint8Array(1);
b = new Uint8ClampedArray(1);
a[0] = 256;
b[0] = 256;

a[0] === 0;    // true
b[0] === 255;  // true
```

I would just use a regular array (if that's an option) and clamp the values when you store them into it, or when you read them to generate your string like this:

```
s += String.fromCharCode(Math.max(0, Math.min(255, array[i])));
```

Comment: Thank so much for the help! Unfortunately using a normal array seems to yield some extra bytes.

For example:

Comment: ...

For example:
A Uint8ClampedArray produces:
3*!l


Whereas your code produces:
3*!l


As far as I can tell, the encoding is 100% the same for visible characters, there just seems to be an additional line-break or something which causes havoc.

Comment: Damn the bytes show in the edit but not when submitted. Could the reason the the addition of some null bytes?

Comment: You should probably handle special characters like 0, but that's true regardless of the type of array used. Maybe console.log(array) to see if there's any difference between the two?

Comment: I found an un-rounded float that was causing one issue, that seems to have fixed it a bit. The only difference I can see between them now is that with the array, ! characters are present, with the clamped array, they show as special characters (you know the strange little box indicating a hex value).

Comment: Got it working :) The last problem was caused by another statically appended value. I was escaping via "x\" when I should have used the plain decimal value. Thanks for you help, you lead me down the right track. I've marked as an excepted answer as you clearly pointed out the unexpected behaviour of the Uint8Array :)

Answer (score 4):

The WhatWG has recommended the Uint8ClampedArray for storing canvas pixel data.

But, various browsers use Uint8ClampedArray (or not) depending on whether they've implemented the WhatWG recommendations.

Therefore, a more cross-browser solution is to pull an array from your canvas using .getImageData and then manipulate that array as desired.  That way you know you're using a compatible array.

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

var data = imageData.data;  // this array is always compatible with its browser.
```

Comment: Nice! A very clean solution. I ended up using a normal array as suggested above but this answer has a definite performance advantage. I would up vote but don't have enough rep (damn SO rules).